# Oracle - inserting cursor data into a custom type table

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, cursor

I have a type like

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE AS OBJECT
(
  id               NUMBER(10, 0),
  name             VARCHAR2(4),
  lastName         VARCHAR2(13),
  address          VARCHAR2(30),
  previousAddress  VARCHAR2(80)
);
```

and a table of these as

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TYPE MY_TYPE_ROWS AS TABLE OF MY_TYPE
```

what I want to do is insert some rows that are returned from a cursor in this "MY_TYPE_ROWS" table. (and i want to do that in a pl/sql procedure)

The data that I want to insert into "MY_TYPE_ROWS" are in a cursor like:

```
cursor dataCursor IS 
select 
id,name, lastName,address,previousAddress
from table1;
```

(cursor returns more than 1 row)

I've tried something like:

```
 my_table_rows           MY_TYPE_ROWS := MY_TYPE_ROWS ();

  OPEN dataCursor ;
  FETCH dataCursor 
  INTO my_table_rows;
  CLOSE dataCursor ;
```

but i am getting an exception "Error: PLS-00386: type mismatch found at 'my_table_rows' between FETCH cursor and INTO variables"

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can't you do like that?

```
declare
  my_table_rows           my_type_rows;
begin
  select my_type(id,name,lastname,address,previousaddress)
  bulk collect into my_table_rows
  from table1;

  -- do whatever you want
end;
```

The problem of your method is that you are trying to select one row by single `into` which even does not contain any object.

And by definition it should be `an array of objects`. So `bulk collect` implements array fetching, and `my_type(id,name,lastname,address,previousaddress)` implements creating the objects of the array.